# DataGridView MaskedTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, and I would like to have something similar to a `MaskedTextBox` inside my `DataGridView`. It doesn't have to be an exact `MaskedTextBox`, but at least somewhat acting like one.

Here is what my [`DataGridView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDZ8Z.png) looks like.

[image: <code>DataGridView</code>]

All I want is that the people who modify the `DataGridView`'s right column (Durée - 'Duration'), follow the Mask pattern `00:00:00` for time.

Another solution would be to place a `DateTimePicker`. But similar to the solution using a `MaskedTextBox`, it does supposedly not exist as `DataGridView` columns.

I have tried using the Column's Builder to add a Behavior→Format, but I don't think this is quite the same. I need something to prevent the user from adding random stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two options:

- You can use a regular `MaskedTextBox` overlaid over the `TextBox` the DGV creates for editing
- You can code the regular edit control, i.e. the `TextBox` the DGV shows when entering edit mode.

Here are examples for both:

First we create class level variables for the controls:

```
TextBox editBox = new TextBox();
MaskedTextBox editMBox = new MaskedTextBox();
```

**To get a reference to the editing textbox** we code the  `EditingControlShowing` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    editBox = e.Control as TextBox;
}
```

To control user input we hook up the `KeyPress` event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ..
    editBox.KeyPress += editBox_KeyPress;
    ..
}
```

Here we can do all sorts of check and prevent bad characters from entering. All the regular properties are there..:

```
void editBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    string sNew = editBox.Text.Substring(0, editBox.SelectionStart)
            + e.KeyChar + editBox.Text.Substring(editBox.SelectionStart);
    Console.WriteLine(sNew);
    e.Handled =  !validateMethod(sNew);
}
```

This would call a function you can write..

**But if you are happy with what a `MaskedTextBox` you can simply use one:**

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
             DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
    editMBox.Parent = dataGridView1;
    editMBox.Location = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cell.ColumnIndex, 
                                  cell.RowIndex, false).Location;
    editMBox.Size = editBox.Size;
    editMBox.Show();
    editMBox.Mask = yourMask;
    editMBox.BringToFront();
}
```

We need to hook up the `KeyPress` event for the `MaskedTextBox` to end to editing. Here is just a simple way to accept the value when `Enter` is pressed.

You will want to handle `Esc` here and also at least the `CurrentCellChanged` event for more complete control..

```
void editMBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        editBox.Text = editMBox.Text;
        editMBox.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found another option, but this looks pretty good. I'll definately check that out if I have to re use those masked textboxes later on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this neat little program [MaskedTextBoxColumn in DataGridViews](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox). I had found that a little earlier, but was reluctant to download it since we had to register and stuff. Actually worked out pretty well. The mask properties is a little too simple, as it is lacking some nice features, but the general MaskedTextBox idea is there.